# Quarkus not picking up Kubernetes environment variable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, quarkus

I have two environments when I am deploying on GitHub, and want to be able to discern between the two in my logs, therefore I have an `ENVIRONMENT` field which is set to either `QA` or `LIVE`.

Here is how I set these fields in `main.tf`:

```
locals {
  environment = {
    qa = "QA"
    live = "LIVE"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "config" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "v1"
    "kind"       = "ConfigMap"
    "metadata" = {
      "name"      = "config"
      "namespace" = "test"
    }
    "data" = {
      "ENVIRONMENT" = local.environment[terraform.workspace],
    }
  }
}
```

This sets the `ENVIRONMENT` field in my configMap. I have confirmed this running `kubectl` commands, and can see this field with in the configMap with the deployment.

I then read this field in my `application.properties` like so:

```
quarkus.log.json.additional-field."environment".value=${ENVIRONMENT:unknown}
```

Because this is set on runtime, it will be set when there is a configMap available to read from, so I am very confused as to why all my logs still say `unknown` for the environment? I am using `quarkus-logging-json` for my logging

Comment: Ok, and what happens when you run `terraform workspace show` in the same directory?

Comment: @MarkoE. Hi, I have resolved the issue now and have posted the solution, was super simple in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line to my `application.properties` resolved the issue.

```
quarkus.kubernetes.env.configmaps=CONFIG_MAP_NAME
```

It seems as though the issue was that the configMap was being deployed correctly in the container, but wasn't setting the values as environment variables in quarkus. This line sets all the values in the configMap as environment variables in Quarkus.